# How to assign more memory to Pivot Cache in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a huge dataset and building a Pivot table using VBA. I have defined the separate cache of the Pivot tables. I have 16  GB Ram. The problem is, while the code is running, it stops at PivotCache saying that there is no enough memory to perform the action. But as I have seen in the task manager that excel is using only 6 GB memory out of 16 GB. Is there any workaround to force excel to use all the memory?

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Based on the quoted figures, seems like you're (ab)using Excel as a database. It's not built for that.

Comment: @BigBen I didn't want to, I was using POWER BI but I found out that the horizontal scroll bar does not work for pivot! Microsoft is still solving that bug since last year!

Answer (score 0):

After lot of thinking, I just found one trick to do it. Here is how I did it -

1st step: I wrote code to build a pivot table from the first 50 records which took less cache.

2nd step: Once the pivot was built, then I the code changes the range of the pivot table from 50 records to the whole huge dataset!

And that's all it works!